# Display messages per second in Grafana influxdb and dropwizard metrics

Tags: dropwizard, metrics, influxdb, grafana, codahale-metrics

I am using dropwizard metrics meter to count the total number of requests my application receives. And i am pushing this meter data to influxdb which i want to show in grafana dashboard.
my influx db data looks like :-

```
time                client             cluster count    fifteen-minute     five-minute               mean-minute        one-minute              server
----                ------             ------- -----    --------------     -----------              -----------          ----------             ------
1507235148003000000 OurImportantClient CL01    56992   50.678040360101775  99.52398667263071      172.70072682021265 80.00874252631192        localhost
1507235148033000000 OurImportantClient CL01    2177    60.95977917444668   31.29599463894603      6.596861684474326  0.717010283038515        localhost
1507235157999000000 OurImportantClient CL01    57604   50.7944205524674    98.26861507721358      169.42222449289022 77.14554982009743        localhost
1507235158033000000 OurImportantClient CL01    2177    60.28619734584058   30.269989895387145     6.40284451016588   0.6069361011507497       localhost
1507235168000000000 OurImportantClient CL01    58189   50.8795672749558    96.9648721158363       166.25254478413774 74.28375646281316        localhost
1507235168034000000 OurImportantClient CL01    2177    59.62005833421925   29.277621588246074     6.219878501675276  0.5137603178004709       localhost
1507235178001000000 OurImportantClient CL01    58764   50.95269899397442   95.67086847891309      163.2315524063629  71.7026680938437         localhost
1507235178032000000 OurImportantClient CL01    2177    58.96127989935249   28.317786983971164     6.047145479629095  0.43488871999209266      localhost .
```

When i am trying to display this in grafana i am seeing a weird graph. What is wrong in my query .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your query seems to be missing.  It looks like you tried to attach images that didn't attach or something

Comment: My bad, somehow the query was not attached. But you can view the query from the above metrics tab.  


SELECT count("mean-minute") FROM "requests" WHERE ("server" =~ /^(localhost)$/) AND time >= now() - 6h GROUP BY time(10s) fill(null)